# Restkit Nested JSON mapRelationship not working

Tags: ios, restkit

**I found my mistake, so please scroll to Update to see what I have done wrong and what other problems I have with RestKit :)**

I have a problem with the following JSON:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "latTitle": "Aale",
        "latExamplesString": "",
        "previewImg": 1,
        "lastModified": null,
        "localeCategory": {
            "id": 1,
            "catID": 1,
            "langCode": "de",
            "localeTitle": "Aale",
            "localeExampleString": "Gefleckter Schlangenaal, Ringelschlangenaal"
        },
        "elements": null
    }
]

As you see, localeCategory is a nested list of attributes, so I have done the following for mapping it:

```
        //creating Mapping for localeCategory
    RKManagedObjectMapping *localeMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LocaleCategory class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
    localeMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"lcatId";
    [localeMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"lcatId"];
    [localeMapping mapKeyPath:@"catId" toAttribute:@"catId"];
    [localeMapping mapKeyPath:@"langCode" toAttribute:@"langCode"];
    [localeMapping mapKeyPath:@"localeTitle" toAttribute:@"localeTitle"];
    [localeMapping mapKeyPath:@"localeExampleString" toAttribute:@"localeExampleString"];

    //creating Mapping for Category
    RKManagedObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
    categoryMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"catId";
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"catId"];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"latTitle" toAttribute:@"latTitle"];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"latExamplesString" toAttribute:@"latExamplesString"];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"previewImg" toAttribute:@"previewImg"];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastModified" toAttribute:@"lastModified"];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"elements" toAttribute:@"elements"];

    [categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"localeCategory" toRelationship:@"localeCategory" withMapping:localeMapping];

    //[categoryMapping mapRelationship:@"localeCategory" withMapping:localeMapping];

    [self setObjectMapping:categoryMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"data/de/category"];
```

My problem ist the following:

When I want to list the data out of the JSON file into my TableView, all attributes of localeCategory are null, for example I want to set the Title of a cell:

```
Category *cat = [data objectAtIndex:absoluteRow];
    LocaleCategory *loccat = [cat localeCategory];
    NSLog(@"gotCategory, check localeCat: %@", loccat.localeTitle);
cell.catTitle.text = cat.localeCategory.localeTitle;
```

I've looked at every SampleCode of RestKit and also in related topics here on stack overflow but I cannot find my mistake!

Thank you in advance for the every help :)

cheers,
Max

UPDATE: I also run into trouble when using FetchRequest:

```
NSLog(@"fetchDataFromDataStore");
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] fetchRequestForResourcePath:self.resourcePath];
NSLog(@"request");
self.data = [Category objectsWithFetchRequest:request];
```

end up with this error:

> 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.

What I am also wondering about is that I can't use this:

```
Category *firstCategory = [Category objectWithPrimaryKeyValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

It says no know class method for selector...

I hope someone helps this to find my mistake, it looks like I made a mistake in the general process of setting things up using Reskit with CoreData!

I am looking forward to your help, thanks a lot!

**Thanks rdelmar!** I already fixed it, but I think that was not the problem. I first used RestKit without CoreData, so I used @synthesize instead of @dynamic in the LocaleCategory class :) I all other classes I have done that switch to dynamic, so yeah it was a silly mistake! :)

**Anyway I still have the problem with the FetchRequest! If someone has an idea, I am very thankful!**

Max

Comment: Your JSON has catID, while in your mapping you're using catId (with lower case d).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'am now fine with RestKit :)

Here is the solution for my problem with:

> 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'

```
        [self setObjectMapping:categoryMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"category" withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSString *resourcePath) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Category fetchRequest];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"latTitle" ascending:YES]];
        return fetchRequest;
    }];
```

And the call:

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] fetchRequestForResourcePath:@"category"];
self.data = [Category objectsWithFetchRequest:request];
```

It's easy when you know how :)